# Is it possible to have Taylor expansion for $f(x+z-1)$ ? where $x$ and $z$ are independent variables.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to have Taylor expansion for the function like  $f(x+z-1)$ ?
where, both $x$ and $z$ are independent variables. If yes, how to do that?
As far as I understood, since this is 'function of function', it involves functional derivative. I am not sure about it though. 
 Basically, I want to know if is it possible to write $f(x+z-1)$ = $f(x+z)$ + (terms involving differentiation of $f$)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can always set $u=x+z-1$ and then Taylor expand $f(u)$. Since $x$ and $z$ are obviously degenerate, the expansion would be the same.

Comment: @loki123 thank you. I will try working with this suggestion.